# How can I replace a string by range?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I need to replace a string by range
Example:

```
string = "this is a string";//I need to replace index 0 to 3 whith another string Ex.:"that"
result = "that is a string";
```

but this need to be dinamically. Cant be replace a fixed word ...need be by range

I have tried

```
           result = string.replaceAt(0, 'that');
```

but this replace only the first character and I want the first to third

Comment: what have you tried? have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods) for string methods?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
function replaceRange(s, start, end, substitute) {
    return s.substring(0, start) + substitute + s.substring(end);
}

var str = "this is a string";
var newString = replaceRange(str, 0, 4, "that"); // "that is a string"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "this is a string";
var newString = str.substr(3,str.length);
var result = 'that'+newString
```

substr returns a part of a string, with my exemple, it starts at character 3 up to str.length to have the last character...

To replace the middle of a string, the same logic can be used...

```
var str = "this is a string";
var firstPart = str.substr(0,7); // "this is "
var lastPart = str.substr(8,str.length); // " string"
var result = firstPart+'another'+lastPart; // "this is another string"
```

Comment: Should probably point out that strings are immutable in javascript, so you don't replace so much as create a new string with a different beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I simple [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) call will do here

```
var str = "this is a string";
var result = "that" + str.substring(4);
```

Check out a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97vSK/).

Comment: yes, this if I want to begin in first char, but if I want to begin in third for example?

Comment: @DevMobile, I'm not sure what you mean. `str.substring(4)` will return all chars from the string from the 4th index to the end.

Comment: I need replace the 4th, 5th, 6th character by other value

Comment: Ex.: "12345678" need to return "123otherString78"