# js string .replace() method with index range

Tags: javascript, node.js

[How can I replace a string by range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568097/how-can-i-replace-a-string-by-range)

I need a function replacing a string, but in certain index range. just like above link.
But there were none of answers that could help me in this situation.

```js
var param = [{start: 3, end: 14}, {start: 19, end: Infinity}];
var str = 'foo foo foo foo foo foo foo';

var output = repStr(
  str,                  // string to assign
  (...param),           // array of objects or a object with "start" and "end" property
  new RegExp(/(foo)/g), // regex (find)
  'bar'                 // replacement string
);

console.log(output);

// expected output: 'foo bar bar foo foo bar bar'
```

I want to make `repStr` function.
It needs to support **Regular Expressions and Array range parameters**, I really need them.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have another example where the replacement is more visable?

Comment: I have edited my post*. I'm sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the second last paramter of [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)'s callback (the actual index) for checking against the wanted ranges.

BTW, your result should look a bit different with the given ranges.

```js
const repStr = (string, regexp, replacement, ranges) => string.replace(regexp, (...p) => {
    const index = p[p.length - 2];
    return ranges.some(({ start, end }) => start <= index && index <= end)
        ? replacement
        : p[0]
});


var param = [ {start: 3, end: 14 },  {start: 19, end: Infinity }],
    //        ************    ********
    //     012345678901234567890123456
    str = 'foo foo foo foo foo foo foo',
    output = repStr(str, new RegExp(/(foo)/g), 'bar', param);

console.log(output); // is different of 'foo bar bar foo foo bar bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all instances of "foo" in substrings between all ranges in the "params"

```
param.reduce((acc,cur) =>(
    acc.substring(0,cur.start)+
    acc.substring(cur.start,cur.end).replace(/foo/g,'bar')+
    acc.substring(cur.end)
  ),str)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it