# How to get first 2 and last 2 characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried this, how can I make it become 'A1****D4'

```
let name = "AlB2C3D4";
let s = name.replace(name.substring(2),"*");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace a string by range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568097/how-can-i-replace-a-string-by-range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try a regex replacement with the help of a callback function:

```js
var name = "AlB2C3D4";
var output = name.replace(/^(..)(.*)(..)$/, (a, b, c, d) => b + c.replace(/./g, "*") + d);
console.log(output);
```

The regex logic here is as follows:

- `^` from the start of the input
- `(..)` match and capture the first 2 characters
- `(.*)` match and capture the middle portion, excluding
- `(..)` the last two characters (but also capture those)
- `$` end of the string

Then, in the callback/lambda function, we build the output, but we run a replace operation on the middle portion of the input, replacing every character with `*` to mask it.

Comment: nice i get it, thanks for fast reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of the last two digits of your string in the substring. Then replace the whole substring by a string of `*` with the length of the removed substring.

```js
const word = "AAAAAAAAAAB";

const pattern = word.substring(0, 2) +
                word.substring(2, word.length - 2).replace(/./g, '*') +
                word.substring(word.length - 2, word.length)

console.log(pattern) // prints AA*******AB
```

Comment: nice answer, easy to let me know the logic

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah you are right. thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer and it should work now as expected. turns out to be like a more nooby version of your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another fancy option would be using the destructuring assignment to create an Array of the String chars.
Then we could use the `Array.prototype.map()` Method to replace any char, thats not matching our condition to asterisk(`*`).

I've also added a variable to change the amount of chars, that should be visible in front and end of the string.

```js
const str = "A1B2C3D4"
const visibleChar = 2;

// We use the Destructuring Assignment Operation, to convert our String into an Array.
// Then we use the .map() Method to change each char to an asterisk 
// by checking if the index of the Char is in the front of the visibleChars 
// or at the end of the string inside the visibleChars amount.
// After the map() method, we join the Array back into a string with .join()
let res = [...str].map((char, i) => i <= (visibleChar-1) || i >= str.length - visibleChar ? char : '*').join("");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I run the code snippet but the answer don't what I want.

Comment: to make the result as you expect it to be you have to change `visibleChar` to `2`, then it does exactly what you expected

Comment: Ouh yeah, sry, i hadn't changed the variable back to 2. My fault.